# Is there a way to fix a Test which should return a string made of ResultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, junit, mockito, resultset

I have a function which creates a string from a result set. And the one that sends messages. You can see them below

```java
public String createStringReport(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
    StringBuilder reportData = new StringBuilder("");
    int columns = 0;
    if(resultSet.getMetaData() != null) {
        columns = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                reportData.append(resultSet.getString(i)).append("\t");
            }
            reportData.append("\n");
        }
    }
    return !reportData.toString().isEmpty() ? reportData.toString() : "No data";
}

private void sendStringReport(String reportData) {
    for (User u: users) {
        sender.send(u, reportData);
        log.info("send report - " + report.getName() + " to" + u.getName());
    }
}
```

I need to write a test which calls sender with the parameter string which was generated before. That's what I have for now:

```java
@Test
public void shouldGenerateStringReportWhenThreadRunHasData() throws SQLException {
    String result = "somestring";
    Report report = getReport(ReportType.STRING);
    ReportCreator reportCreator = new
            StringReportCreator(report, users, sender, dataSource, unexpectedErrorCounter);

    when(resultSet.getString(anyInt())).thenReturn(result);

    when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    int columns = 2;
    final ResultSetMetaData rsmd = mock(ResultSetMetaData.class);
    when(resultSet.getMetaData()).thenReturn(rsmd);
    doReturn(rsmd).when(resultSet).getMetaData();

    StringBuilder reportData = new StringBuilder("");
    if(resultSet.getMetaData() != null) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                reportData.append(result).append("\t");
            }
            reportData.append("\n");
        }
    }

    reportCreator.run();
    verify(sender, Mockito.times(users.size())).send(any(User.class), eq(reportData.toString));
}
```

Unfortunately, I am told:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
telegramSender.send(
    <any reportbot.entity.User>,
    "somestring somestring  
somestring  somestring  
"
);
-> at ru.phoenixdnr.reportbot.ReportCreatorTest$Run.shouldGenerateStringReportWhenThreadRunHasData(ReportCreatorTest.java:233)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
telegramSender.send(
    User(id=1, idTelegram=2, name=892e0f69-c10e-4961-b22e-11de333fbb55, email=73507828-9c7a-4026-8599-5e6c8c62e3c7),
    "No data"
);
```

Why is the reportData empty?
How can I fix this? I've been trying for a week now, but nothing helps.

Comment: Are there any other ways to test verify method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you:

- set up the mock result set,
- read the results out of it while constructing the expected output,
- call the method you are trying to test, *with the same result set*.

When the method under test runs, it finds that the result set has already been exhausted (or at least `.next()` returns `false`), so there is no more data to read from it.  Hence you get no data.

You wouldn't have this problem if the code that generates the expected text used a separate result set.

One way to fix this is to move all of your `ResultSet` mock setup code into a separate method, which creates and returns the mock `ResultSet`.  That way you can call this method twice to get two different mock `ResultSet`s, one to create a result set to use to create the expected result, and once to pass to the report creator.

Another fix is to generate the expected output without using the mock `ResultSet`.  You know that `ResultSet.getMetaData()` won't return `null`, so the null-check is unnecessary, and you also know how many rows are in the mock `ResultSet`, so you can replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, the matter was in exausted ```resultSet.next()```
Now I will not repeat the same mistake )

Answer (score 0):

You missed mocking the `ResultSetMetadata`'s `getColumnCount` call:

```java
when(rsmd.getColumnCount()).thenReturn(2);
```

Comment: Yes, I missed it. However, I have put it now, and nothing has changed... same error